# ElasticSearch new Java API print created quesy

Tags: elasticsearch

I trying out the new Java Client for Elastic 8.1.1.
In older versions i was able to print out the generated json query by using  `searchRequest.source()`.

I cannot find out actuallay what methode/service i can use do to so with the new client.
My code looks:

```
    final Query range_query = new Query.Builder().range(r -> r.field("pixel_x")
            .from(String.valueOf(lookupDto.getPixel_x_min())).to(String.valueOf(lookupDto.getPixel_x_max())))
            .build();

    final Query bool_query = new Query.Builder().bool(t -> t.must(range_query)).build();

    SearchRequest sc = SearchRequest.of(s -> s.query(bool_query).index(INDEX).size(100));
```

The SearchRequest object offers a `source()` method but ist value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for printing query with new Elastic Java Client:

```java
Query termQuery = TermQuery.of(t -> t.field("field_name").value("search_value"))._toQuery();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator generator = JacksonJsonProvider.provider().createGenerator(writer);
termQuery.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
generator.flush();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: Ui, its quite more to setup even to decide if debug is enabled, but it works so far. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's correct